# Should I use constant in any shape or form when pointing towards a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

**My question is:** should I have a constant pointer point towards a dynamic array of data? Or if I am wrong on everything I just said explain maybe a little further of what the problems are with constants pointers.

**In depth:**

I was working with a ***constant pointer*** that would point towards a "**new int[ # ]** " and then once I was done with that and the array's use was over, I would normally think to set this to ***NULL*** after freeing the memory using ***delete[]*** so that the pointer wouldn't be a garbled up memory location.

Thus, I realized that if this was declared to have a constant memory address then after freeing up the memory it will still be pointed towards where the original array started from. And since it's constant it will always occupy the same amount of space ( is that true ? ). This also means that I can't even set it to a newly created integer from the free store. Why? Because doesn't creating NEW variables set the pointer to a different memory location. Therefor dynamic arrays shouldn't ever be constant when it comes towards a different range of array lengths.

Comment: If this is what you mean then I have not seen it:

`int * const p = new int[8]; 
...
delete[] p;
p = NULL;  // <-- this is an error. `

Can you give an example of when this is useful?

It usually comes down to a problem of scope OR returning a const from a function so that the caller is encouraged not to fiddle with it.

Comment: A pointer can be constant in three ways, for example: `const int *`, `int * const`, and `const int * const`.  The first makes the data constant, the second makes the address constant, and the third makes both constant.

Comment: @SilverCode I think that actually may be the answer. I don't think it's useful at all. I didn't think about it when I wrote the code. I just thought to make sure the address couldn't be changed whence it has been set, but then I realized that it might not even be able to free memory and carry new data.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey thanks, I did some practice already on constants and what you said is embedded in my head.